# Number of links between two Wikipedia pages

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I have been successfully able to use the Wikipedia pagelinks SQL dump to obtain hyperlinks between Wikipedia pages for a specific revision time.

However, there are cases where multiple instances of such links exist, e.g. the very same https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia page and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Foundation. I'm interested to find number of links between pairs of pages for a specific revision.

Ideal solutions would involve dump files other than pagelinks (which I'm not aware of), or using the MediaWiki API.

Answer (score 1):

I think your least bad option is to parse the Parsoid output; e.g. go to https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/Wikipedia and count the links matching the selector `a[rel="mw:WikiLink"][href="./Wikimedia_Foundation"]`.

Comment: I would have to make an api call and parse for every hyperlink between any two wikipedia articles ...

Comment: You would have to, yes. You could try asking on the [research list](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wiki-research-l/) - maybe someone did it already and can share the data.